# Unable to install mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, mysql

Can anyone help me in installing mysql 5.7.
I tried following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232558/install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04), but when I run

```
sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
```

It gives me:

```
8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
    500 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
    500 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
5.7.31-1ubuntu18.04 500
    500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
```

Which are different from the linked answer.

When I tried to

```
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7.30-1ubuntu18.04
```

It gives me error

```
Version '5.7.30-1ubuntu18.04' for 'mysql-client' was not found.
```

When I run `sudo apt install -f mysql-client-5.7` command it installed mysql version.
I also does not finds `mysql-community-server=5.7.30-1ubuntu18.04`.

I tried to run `sudo apt install -f mysql-community-server` It gives me following error:

```
mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-client (= 5.7.31-1ubuntu18.04) but 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mysql 5.7 is not available to the Ubuntu 20.04. Only mysql 8.0 and higher version are available to Ubuntu 20.04 when you use mysql repository. Here you are using bionic source list (Ubuntu 18.04) for Ubuntu 20.04. I believe this workaround sometimes causes messup with dependencies tree.

You need to download mysql 5.7 packages with their dependencies from [official mysql site here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html) and install manually by executing below command in terminal.

```
sudo dpkg -i <package name>
```

Comment: When tried to run ``` sudo dpkg -i mysql-community-server_5.7.31-1ubuntu18.04_i386.deb ```
 mysql-community-server:i386 : Depends: perl:i386 but it is not installed

Comment: @MaazAnzar You don't have to install 32 bit packages as well if you're having 64 bit OS.

Comment: Thanks It worked!! I first installed related Libraries and than install mysql

Comment: In case others have similar trouble: I downloaded the entire `DEB Bundle` package on that link. Then, I extracted the tarball into its own folder. Once inside the folder, I ran `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. Halfway through the installation process, it failed on `mysql-community-client`. Apparently certain dependencies were unmet. In order to fix this, I had to run `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`. Then, I was able to re-run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and it finished successfully. The Oracle docs were also useful to me: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/linux-installation-debian.html

Answer (score 6):

The later error `mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-client (= 5.7.31-1ubuntu18.04) but 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed` is occurred because of multiple versions of MySQL available. When you tried to install mysql-community-server 5.7, APT tried to fetch latest mysql-client which is 8.0 since all have same priority and that's incompatible with MySQL 5.7.

Though installing packages one by one using DPKG as mentioned by [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1260766/1107512) is fine but that may be long manual task.

To make APT fetch mysql-client 5.7, consider changing priorities. To do that run

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
```

and add

```
Package: mysql-server
Pin: version 5.7*
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-client
Pin: version 5.7*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Retry installation process. `sudo apt install mysql-server` should now fetch 5.7 by default.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! All work for me.

Comment: I tried this and it sends me the same error  : Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 mysql-server : Dépend: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.38-1ubuntu18.04) mais ne sera pas installé

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7.30-1ubuntu18.04
```

should be:

```
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7.31-1ubuntu18.04
```

I landed on your question with the same problem and solved this by looking here http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mysql-5.7/binary-amd64/Packages

Comment: This works well. The link in the answer works and shows .33 at the moment I've checked it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing here quite worked for me, perhaps because I was installing in a Dockerfile.  Here's what did work

```
sed -i -e 's|focal|bionic|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get -qq update
apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y mysql-client-5.7
```

Either do that last thing, or you could always set your `sources.list` back to focal with

```
sed -i -e 's|bionic|focal|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: This one worked fine with one note: had to install Perl in addition to mysql-server-5.7.