# Support for mysql 5.7 for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, 22.04

I am trying to install mysql 5.7 on Ubuntu 22.04 but not able to find the options to install.

Getting errors like :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-client (= 5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04) but 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to install deprecated software on a new system. Your best option is to isolate the old software in containers, for instance with Docker (I believe this is one of the reasons for containers in the first place).

This is the current Docker image for [MySQL 5.7](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/5.7/images/sha256-933bcfdb15aa93f4cfc0dad61da7e88652a3e87d6b69cf87ecbde22226ed5e0d?context=explore).

It is possible to [hack your way through](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232558/install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04) by customizing repositories and configurations, but it's unlikely to end well in the long run.